# Groovy Grails: how to set path of log4j.properties that works in Windows and Linux

Tags: tomcat, grails, log4j, grails-2.1

In `groovy` `grails` project, I want to externalized `log4j.properties` file and I want to make generic relative path to make it work in `Linux` and `Windows`.

To externalize, I have removed `log4j = { ... }` code from `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`
And updated the file `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy` with the following code.

```
beans = {
    log4jConfigurer(org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean) {
        targetClass = "org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer"
        targetMethod = "initLogging"
        arguments = ["./log4j.properties"]
    }
}
```

The `log4j.properties` file is in root directory of `tomcat`, where `webapps, conf,` etc folders exists. 
`/tomcat/log4j.properties`

The above code works on `Windows` but not in `linux` machine.

I have tried the following:

1. Setting the following:

   ```
    arguments = ["${System.properties['catalina.home']}/log4j.properties"]
   ```
2. Also I have tried setting a value `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy` as

   ```
    grailsApplication.config.log4j_path = "${System.properties['catalina.home']}/log4j.properties"
   ```

And tried using it in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy` file as:

```
 arguments = [grailsApplication.config.log4j_path]
```

but non worked.

Can someone tell me how can I set path so that it can work in both `Windows` and `Linux`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is catalina.home set correctly on Linux install?, can you try catalina.base instead, you could also try arguments = ["classpath:log4j.properties"]

Comment: cataline.home is set correctly. I have also tried classpath:log4j.properties. But non worked. When I tried classpath:log4j.properties. the file is in the same tomcat root directory.

Comment: Does the `arguments = ["classpath:log4j.properties"]` option work if you move log4j.properties file to WEB-INF/lib ?

Comment: I really appreciate your inputs. But I wanted to externalise log4j.properties file from the war file.

Comment: Understand, I think the simplest method to determine if log4jConfigurer is working with Linux is to put it in known classpath location then work toward being more specific with location

Comment: I tried `arguments = ["classpath:log4j.properties"]` and placing the `log4j.properties` file in WEB-INF/lib folder. it did not work.

Comment: you can use System.properties['os.name'].contains('Windows') to know if the system is windows

Comment: isn't it just a permission issue?